# Fullcalendar in "agendaWeek" - how to render the days of the week in past unaccessible (grey, unable to select)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

My fullcalendar.io is displayed in 'defaultView: "agendaWeek",' mode. I want to make the cells of the current week grey if the the days of the week are in the past.

For example, if today is Wednesday, the calendar displays `"Apr 19 — 25, 2015"`, so Monday and Tuesday (all their cells without the events) should be grey and unable to select.

I figure it has to do with `viewRender`, here's what it looks like now (it doesn't allow to go back in the past which whant I want also):

```
 viewRender: function(currentView) {
  var minDate = moment();
  if (minDate >= currentView.start && minDate <= currentView.end) {
    $(".fc-prev-button").prop('disabled', true); 
    $(".fc-prev-button").addClass('fc-state-disabled'); 
  }
  else {
    $(".fc-prev-button").removeClass('fc-state-disabled'); 
    $(".fc-prev-button").prop('disabled', false); 
  };

  debugger
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [select](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/) event and [eventRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

> A callback that will fire after a selection is made.

Then you can use [unselect](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/unselect_method/) method to programmatically clearing the current selection.

*Code example*

```
select: function (start, endDate) {
    var minDate = moment();
    if (minDate >= endDate) {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('unselect');
        return;
    }
},
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    var minDate = moment();
    if (minDate >= event.end) {
        $(element).addClass('fc-state-disabled');
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I need but not all.

Comment: Still not all. **For example, if today is Wednesday, the calendar displays "Apr 19 — 25, 2015", so Monday and Tuesday (all their cells without the events) should be grey and unable to select.** I need to make the ordinary cells in the past disabled (or grey or something like that) , not only the ones with the events. So `eventRender` doesn't help here.